# Unable to install Service Bus 1.1 using Web Platform installer

Tags: azure, servicebus

Setup:
Clean Windows 2012 R2 with latest updates running in Generation 2 VM on Hyper-V enabled Windows 10 pro, IIS and .Net3.5 SP1 all prerequisites installed.

Installed WPI v5 and then tried to install Windows Azure Pack: Service Bus 1.1
[image: installation option]

Then getting this

[image: Failure using WPI]

pointing the primary feed to

> http://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/5.0/webproductlist.xml

did not change anything.

Looking at the log I noticed the following warning and Errors:

```
.
.
.
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Error getting last-modified header, error code: 12150
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : HttpQueryInfoWithRetry for HTTP_QUERY_LAST_MODIFIED failed.
.
.
.
DownloadManager Error: 0 : Signature verification failed on downloaded file. URL: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=324000&CLCID=0x409. File location: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\ServiceBus_1_1\8B8FF6B3C0CC7B846F63F905AC56794A945DE4E0\Service_Bus.msi. File size: 7421 kb
```

Trying to download offline copies of the files using the following command:

```
WebpiCmd.exe /offline /Products:ServiceBus_1_1 /Path:C:\temp
```

Ended up with the following errors:
[image]

Then installation command failed with the following:
[image]

Updating the webproductlist.xml of the offline installer according to this [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/390145a6-b38d-480c-b9e7-376a85b2c284/service-bus-11-installation-failed-on-windows-2008-r2-core?forum=servbus)  did not change the outcome.

Am I missing something because being the only one on the web with such a problem means I am doing something wrong ☹

Any one successfully installed Service Bus 1.1 on 2012 R2 in a VM?

Any Ideas?

Comment: I've just did what you are trying to do without any issues...

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit... what are the steps exactly? I am sure I am missing something or I have a configuration on my host system that causing the issue.

Comment: I just installed WebPI and clicked install Service Bus 1.1, that's it.I will try tomorrow with a clean install with updates (this one is not really clean + not all updates are installed).
My setup: w10 ent, hyper-v, 2012 r2.

Comment: I am starting to believe my company firewall or the anti-virus system we use is playing tricks on me.  I will try to do this at home and see... Thanks.

Comment: If you try it "at home", you may already have some dependencies installed.  So you may need a "clean" machine that has no dependencies installed, then run the "offline" command line, and it will get multiple/several packages....  But I agree that your work is doing some voodoo on you;

Comment: I downloaded the Wep Installer files offline at home and they worked without a problem at my work VM..  

Still the biggest suspect is my company firewall..

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your .net framework to 4.6 first. You can use the offline installer:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48137

Then, try once again the service bus 1.1.

Comment: I did that with no success... actually I was able to setup the complete Azure pack setup with all extentions but only the service bus download fails.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same setup at home and it worked without any issues...

Three things come to minde:

1. my company firewall and Antivirus systems are missing up with
   thisdownload.
2. Updates are delivered to the VMS using a central
   system   which may caused a corruption somewhere.
3. It was a bad dream lastedtwo weeks.... ughhh

Comment: glad you sorted that out.